# function wait until it return value

Tags: jquery

Look into this ugly code; this have been written by a programmer who is doing programming from last 2 years almost.

```
var path = "ESP.php?action=ProjectModeChangeRequestHandle&vars=2&var1=" + status + "&var2=" + recordId;
$jq.get(path, {}, function(data) {
    if (data == 1 && status == 1) {
        var go_path = "ESP.php?action=updateProjectInfo&vars=3&var1=" + ID + "&var2=" + StatusID + "&var3=" + ModeID;
        $jq.get(go_path, {}, function(data) {
            getProjectModeChangeRequestListForEveryKindOfUser()
        });
    } else {
        getProjectModeChangeRequestListForEveryKindOfUser();
    }
    newboardfn();
});
```

Now the problem is, how to not repeat the outer GET request as I have to use it some different locations as well. I can easily make function where i could written get request responses but how to wait until function return me the value it?

Comment: Please clarify why you don't want to just declare it as a function?

Comment: Why not wrapped GET request inside function, and later call it using .done or else

Comment: how with done or else? that is the key to ask